# How can use Unix on Windows 10 by Python?

Tags: python, bash, unix

I'm learning Python by the book 'Think Python.'

My computer's OS is Windows 10.

I tried using **os.popen** ('14.8 Pipes' in http://www.greenteapress.com/thinkpython/html/thinkpython015.html) but the book provides an example on Unix.
I want to run Unix on Python script out of curiosity.

I already installed Git bash and Virtual box, but I don't know how to connect and to use Python.

Comment: Is your question, "How do I set up a Unix environment in Windows 10" or "How can I run a script designed for Unix on Windows?"

Comment: @Nathan My question is second."How can I run a script designed for Unix on windows?"

Comment: Windows has pipes. This is an XY problem

Comment: What error do you get when you run your program under Windows?  Have you installed python onto Windows?  Please show your script (not a link) and the full error message.

Answer (score 1):

The example provided by the book is:

> 14.8  Pipes
>
> Most operating systems provide a command-line interface, also known as
> a shell. Shells usually provide commands to navigate the file system
> and launch applications. For example, in Unix you can change
> directories with cd, display the contents of a directory with ls, and
> launch a web browser by typing (for example) firefox.
>
> Any program that you can launch from the shell can also be launched
> from Python using a pipe. A pipe is an object that represents a
> running program.
>
> For example, the Unix command ls -l normally displays the contents of
> the current directory (in long format). You can launch ls with
> os.popen1:
>
> `>>> cmd = 'ls -l'`
>
> `>>> fp = os.popen(cmd)`

It appears you are getting tripped up converting the `ls` command which lists directory contents on *nix to a Windows command. If you search for "what is the windows version of ls" in a search engine, you will discover that Windows provides similar functionality through `dir`. For more useful conversions check out the conversion table on [lemonda.net](https://www.lemoda.net/windows/windows2unix/windows2unix.html).

Changing the code to

`>>> cmd = 'dir'` and calling it via

`>>> fp = os.popen(cmd)`

Should enable the example to run on Windows.

Comment: Thank you!! I already tried your way. but I got curious  how to run Unix on Window by Python script

Answer (score 0):

if you have the latest update of windows 10 you can use Ubuntu, a version of Linux, from your command prompt by just typing the word 'bash' and waiting on it to download some files.  if you see a $ at the end of your command line you got it.  after that just type 'sudo apt-get install python' and enter your windows password when it asks for your password hit the 'Y' key when it asks if you are sure. then you should be able to go from the book from there.

**EDIT:** I believe you have to run cmd as administrator to install bash. You also may have to enable it by hitting the 'windows key + r' to open the run window then type 'appwiz.cpl to open the uninstall window and then click the button on the left of the screen that says 'Turn Windows features on or off', then wait for that to load and then go check the box by 'Windows Subsystems for Linux (Beta)' and then trying to type 'bash' in an elevated cmd prompt.